# I have set the Prometheus retention time to 6 months, but the incoming data still defaults to 15 days

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, prometheus-node-exporter

I have set the Prometheus retention time to 6 months, but the incoming data still defaults to 15 days

I set the incoming data for 6 months as below in the configuration /etc/systemd/system/prometheus.service

--storage.tsdb.retention.size 25GB 
--storage.tsdb.retention.time 180d

but the incoming data is still 15 days, is there any configuration that needs to be set again?